# Upper and lower bounds for frozen distribution object in scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy

When creating a frozen `rv_continuous` distribution in `scipy.stats`, I expected that the parameters that specify the bounds (`a` and `b`) would be automatically filled correctly, but they do not seem to be:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import uniform
>>> d = uniform(20, 40) # U[20,60] distribution
>>> d.a # expect 20, get 0
0.0
>>> d.b # expect 60, get 1
1.0
```

The methods work OK:

```
>>> d.mean() # expect 40, get 40
40.0
>>> d.interval(1) # expect [20,60], get [20,60]
(20.0, 60.0)
```

(`d.interval(1)` basically does the trick here since I want to get the bounds.)

Is there something I have to do to get `.a` and `.b` to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging around in the source code and from my understanding no, there is no way to update those attributes.

a and b are defined as 0 and 1 by default in line 7914 of [_continuous_distns.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py)

```
uniform = uniform_gen(a=0.0, b=1.0, name='uniform')
```

But I then couldn't see any example of those variables actually being used. Rather the lower and upper bounds are set with the loc and scale parameters where the lower bound is equal to loc and the upper bound is equal to loc + scale.

The best way to get the upper and lower bounds I would say is to use the support method

```
uniform(20,40).support()
>>>
(20,60)
```